# UEFI - EDK2 - Hooking SetVariable results in UNEXCEPTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP

Tags: c, windows, hook, uefi, blue-screen-of-death

I'm coding a UEFI Runtime Driver for Windows which hooks `gRT->SetVariable(...)`

Hooking seems to work fine but whenever I startup a user-mode application and call `SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable(...)` it reults in a Bluescreen saying `UNEXCEPTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP`.

I cannot find any solution for this. Here are a few things iam aware of:

- I'm raising TPL
- I recalculate and set CRC32
- On `SetVirtualAddressMap(...)` i convert all my pointer

Google didn't help at all. So i really wonder what causes this Bluescreen and how i may proceed to resolve this issue.

What am i missing? Am i doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
ExchangePointerInServiceTable((VOID**)&gST->RuntimeServices->SetVariable,
        (VOID*)HookedSetVariable,
        (VOID**)&gOriginalSetVariable);
```

```
static
EFI_STATUS
ExchangePointerInServiceTable(
    IN OUT VOID** AddressToUpdate,
    IN VOID* NewPointer,
    OUT VOID** OriginalPointer OPTIONAL
)
{
    EFI_STATUS status;
    EFI_TPL tpl;

    ASSERT(*AddressToUpdate != NewPointer);

    tpl = gBS->RaiseTPL(TPL_HIGH_LEVEL);

    if (OriginalPointer != NULL)
    {
        *OriginalPointer = *AddressToUpdate;
    }
    *AddressToUpdate = NewPointer;

    gST->Hdr.CRC32 = 0;
    status = gBS->CalculateCrc32(&gST->Hdr, gST->Hdr.HeaderSize, &gST->Hdr.CRC32);
    ASSERT_EFI_ERROR(status);

    gBS->RestoreTPL(tpl);
    return status;
}
```

```
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
HookedSetVariable(
    IN CHAR16* VariableName,
    IN EFI_GUID* VendorGuid,
    IN UINT32 Attributes,
    IN UINTN DataSize,
    IN VOID* Data
) {
    if (StrCmp(VariableName, gStrComVarName) == 0) {
        COMMUNICATION_PROTOCOL * comVarPtr = (COMMUNICATION_PROTOCOL*)Data;
        switch (comVarPtr->i8OperationId) {
        case COMMUNICATION_PROTOCOL_OPERATION_PING:
            comVarPtr->i8OperationId = COMMUNICATION_PROTOCOL_PONG;
        }
        CopyMem(Data, comVarPtr, DataSize);
    }
    
    return gOriginalSetVariable(VariableName, VendorGuid, Attributes, DataSize, Data);
}
```

Edit: While in UEFI, other UEFI Applications correctly call the hooked `SetVariable(...)` without any further problems.
This may bring it down to the problem only existing after VirtualAddressSpace has been created from the OS.

Comment: Does the error message indicate what fault occurred, and at what address? Is it in your hook function, or before it is called, or after it returns?

Comment: Are you sure your UEFI runtime driver is still loaded and accessible at the same virtual address?

Comment: Isn’t CopyMem in boot services, not runtime services? In any case, the call to CopyMem is unnecessary; the source and destination are the same.

Comment: Where is gStrComVarName stored? Is it still accessible at the time your hook function is called?

Comment: If you haven’t already, I suggest you test this with a UEFI program before trying it with a Windows program, to concentrate on one set of problems at a time.

Comment: @prl regarding the error message: i cannot find anymore information to this.
Error log only gives me error code: `0x0000007f (0x0000000000000008, 0xfffff80654280e50, 0xffffa68e94898ee0, 0xfffff80650c5844a).`

I think it should still be loaded but how may i find out?

I removed CopyMem call. Still BSOD.

With another UEFI application i can easily call the hooked SetVariable.

gStrComVarName in stored in global scope. But i saw that i did not convert its pointer. I do that now. Still BSOD.

Comment: Searching for UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP finds some useful information. For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7f--unexpected-kernel-mode-trap and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-code-reference2.

Comment: 0x7f means UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP; 8 means double fault. The addresses indicate that it is not in your driver (because they would be less than 0x100000000) but other than that I don't know how to interpret them. You probably need a Windows debugger (windbg).

Comment: Can you figure out a way to tell when your hook function is called (trace, for example), so you can tell if the error occurs before it is called or after it returns?